# geocode inside a function in a controller

Tags: angularjs, infinite

I try to get a get code by a function inside a controller. Then I got this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

It seems to be an infinite thing. Can you help me?

```
app.controller('mapCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.search = function() {
            $http.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=haiphong')
                .then(function(response) {
                     //First function handles success
                     $scope.content = response.data;
                }, function(response) {
                     //Second function handles error
                     $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
                });
            }
    }
)
```

This is the view file:

```
<div ng-app="weatherForecast" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
       <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 clearfix">
       {{city.formatted_address}}

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
     <div class="map-wrapper">
      <div id="map">
       {{init()}}
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add your view file. This mostly happends when you call `$scope functions` in your view inside iterations.

Comment: I added the view snippet. Can you take a look on it?

Comment: Where is your `$scope.search()` used in the view and what does `{{init()}}`?

Comment: yes, I changed init() by search() and this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Well, putting an function directly into a `E2E` binding like `{{init()}}` will constantly calling this function when a async function is inside your scope like `$http.jsonp()`. If I understand you right your `init()` function should be initialize your HTTP call. So use `ng-init` to make it work. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unx87cjn/3/) shows you how to handle it right. Take a look near `<div id="map" ng-init="search()">`.

Please note that your API endpoint https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=haiphong is not returning JSONP so you dont need to access the data with `$http.jsonp()`.

Please note also that your API endpoint is not supporting [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). Thats why you wount be able to fetch this data async with AngularJS.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
              <input class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 clearfix">
              {{content}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="map-wrapper">
            <div id="map" ng-init="search()">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.search = function() {
            $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=haiphong')
               .then(function(response) {
                     //First function handles success
                     $scope.content = response.data;
                }, function(response) {
                     //Second function handles error
                     $scope.content = response.data || 'Request failed';
                });
        }
}
```

Comment: you are right. Thanks you so much. I voted for this answer ;)

Comment: @vuquanghoang  glad to help. Mark this answer as right. So it could help other users. Well, there is no upvote right now, looks like you did not vote =(